# React Image Source Tag Rendering Object Module Instead

Tags: reactjs, object, styled-components

I am exporting an object with properties associated with an information component. I am trying to have the image display within a styled image component. What is happening is I'm not seeing the image, but instead a tiny broken image icon is displaying. And 'object Module' within the src element. No errors in the developer console about it and nothing about it in the terminal when the app is running.

What's the problem here?
Thanks,
Ironman

Object with Image Props--

**Data.js**

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  id: "home",
  lightBg: false,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: "Hello",
  headline: "Thank you for helping me with this issue",
  buttonLabel: "Appreciated!",
  imgStart: false,
  img: require("./speed-test.svg"),
  alt: "x",
  dark: true,
  primary: true,
  darkText: false,
};
```

The styled components the image is to display in--

**InfoElements.js**

```
export const ImgWrap = styled.div`
  max-width: 555px;
  height: 100%;
`;

export const Img = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding-right: 0;
`;
```

The Image Component Properties Passed In--

**InfoSection.js**

```
 <ImgWrap>{<Img src={img} alt={alt} />}</ImgWrap>
```

Comment: Try using `require("./speed-test.svg").default`

Comment: `console.log(img)`. It looks like it's currently an object. It has to be a string (the actual resolved URL).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply using '.default'.  Supplied by the first commenter. Thanks.